# Issue in NDK Native camera in some device

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-code

I am using NDK native camera for my app. But i am facing a camera preview issue in my one device which contains **hardware level 2** while it's **android version is greater than 7(nougat)**(which is required for using NDK native camera). But due to hardware level 2 of my device, i am unable to accessing NDK native camera. Because due to hardware level 2, it is giving cameraListId=0

Anybody know actual reason? , why NDK Native camera doesn't support that device which contains to hardware level 2 ?

And does any native code available for accessing camera of android device which doesn't have any restriction of android version and hardware level of device ?

Comment: There are too many unknowns here. We don't know what _"unable to accessing NDK native camera"_ means, because you haven't shown us any error messages, log messages, function return values, or the code that causes them.

Comment: @Michael can we open NDK native camera in such device which contains android version >= 7 and hardware level 2 ?